# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API stream file directly from MinIO

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, minio

My task is to get a `.pdf` file from MinIO storage and show it in application.

If file has a big size I have to wait a lot time before it downloads from MinIO and I can start to send it to UI.

This is my code sample:

```
public async Task<byte[]> DownloadAsync(Guid fileId, string? fileTag = default, Guid? versionId = default)
{
    var bucketName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileTag) ? _defaultBucketName : fileTag;

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var minioClient = CreateMinioClient();

    var args = new GetObjectArgs();
    args.WithBucket(bucketName);
    args.WithObject(fileId.ToString());
    args.WithCallbackStream((stream) => stream.CopyTo(memoryStream));
    // args.WithRequestBody()

    if (versionId != null)
    {
        args.WithVersionId(versionId.ToString());
    }

    await minioClient.GetObjectAsync(args);

    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

As we can see we get stream in callback method and have to copy it to memory before we can send it to frontend.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("gettestpdf")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<FileResult> GetTestPdf()
{
    var fileData = await _fileLoader.DownloadAsync(Guid.Parse("e691e105-5240-4df5-a02f-e5d8e7a73b36"), "pdf");

    var memStream = new MemoryStream();
    memStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return File(memStream, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
}
```

But if the `.pdf` document is linearized, we can start to view it before it fully loads.

Is here a way to start sending the `.pdf` file stream from storage to the UI before we copy the full stream? Some way to send stream bytes from MinIO before object will load and copied fully?

Comment: In fact ,you could return File(fileData, "application/pdf", "test.pdf"); directly, without copying it to another stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution!

We can get link instead on object

```
        public async Task<string> GetDownloadLinkAsync(Guid fileId, string? fileTag = null, Guid? versionId = null)
    {
        var bucketName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileTag) ? _defaultBucketName : fileTag;

        var minioClient = CreateMinioClient();

        var args = new PresignedGetObjectArgs()
            .WithBucket(bucketName)
            .WithObject(fileId.ToString())
            .WithExpiry(1200);

        return await minioClient.PresignedGetObjectAsync(args);
    }
```

And then send it as a PhisycalFileResult.

```
        [HttpGet]
    [Route("gettestpdf")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<PhysicalFileResult> GetTestPdf()
    {
        var downloadUrl = await _fileLoader.GetDownloadLinkAsync(Guid.Parse("e691e105-5240-4df5-a02f-e5d8e7a73b36"), "pdf");
        return PhysicalFile(downloadUrl, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
    }
```

As result, we download it only once (from MinIO to UI) and we can view it before it will be downloaded fully (because pdf file is linearized).